# How to change date to days ago (human time diff)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, date

I'm using the WordPress theme Newspaper.  Right now the date is appearing as "July 26, 2017", but I would like it to appear as "4 hours ago", or "3 days ago".  After looking around, I've found there is a WordPress code that will do this.  However, I can't figure out how to replace the current date of my site with human time diff.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

The get date function my theme uses:

```
    function get_date($show_stars_on_review = true) {
        $visibility_class = '';
        if (td_util::get_option('tds_m_show_date') == 'hide') {
            $visibility_class = ' td-visibility-hidden';
        }

        $buffy = '';
        if ($this->is_review and $show_stars_on_review === true) {
            //if review show stars
            $buffy .= '<div class="entry-review-stars">';
            $buffy .=  td_review::render_stars($this->td_review);
            $buffy .= '</div>';

        } else {
            if (td_util::get_option('tds_m_show_date') != 'hide') {
                $td_article_date_unix = get_the_time('U', $this->post->ID);
                $buffy .= '<span class="td-post-date">';
                    $buffy .= '<time class="entry-date updated td-module-date' . $visibility_class . '" datetime="' . date(DATE_W3C, $td_article_date_unix) . '" >' . get_the_time(get_option('date_format'), $this->post->ID) . '</time>';
                $buffy .= '</span>';
            }
        }

        return $buffy;
    }
```

Where the function is called:

```
    <div class="item-details">
        <?php echo $this->get_title();?>
        <div class="td-module-meta-info">
            <?php if (td_util::get_option('tds_category_module_mx1') == 'yes') { echo $this->get_category(); }?>
            <span class="td-author-date">
                <?php echo $this->get_author();?>
                <?php echo $this->get_date();?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="td-excerpt">
            <?php echo $this->get_excerpt();?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The human time diff code:

```
<?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?>
```

the element where I am trying to change the date

```html
<?php

class td_module_2 extends td_module {

    function __construct($post) {
        //run the parrent constructor
        parent::__construct($post);
    }

    function render() {
        ob_start();
        ?>

        <div class="<?php echo $this->get_module_classes();?>">
            <div class="td-module-image">
                <?php echo $this->get_image('td_324x160');?>
                <?php if (td_util::get_option('tds_category_module_2') == 'yes') { echo $this->get_category(); }?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->get_title();?>


            <div class="td-module-meta-info">
                <?php echo $this->get_author();?>
                <?php echo wp_relative_date(get_the_time('U'));?>
            </div>


            <div class="td-excerpt">
                <?php echo $this->get_excerpt();?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->get_quotes_on_blocks();?>

        </div>

        <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the functions.php file add

```
function wp_relative_date($post_date)
{
    return human_time_diff( $post_date , current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . ' ago';
}
```

To display the time add this within the loop

```
echo wp_relative_date(get_the_time('U'));
```

Comment: How would I specifically add this to my theme?  I have the code above (inside the item details class)

Comment: You can simply put the first part outside the class on functions.php file. Is it under a class or namespace?

Comment: I placed the code of the element I changed the date on above in my answer.  Does it look right?  It's saying all dates are 6 days ago, even if they were 10 days ago or 10 hours ago?

Comment: Do you think it is because of the function get_date that the theme already had?  Do you think I just have to edit that code? ( the first code in my question above)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that converts to either minutes, hours, or days based on the set current date and time with post date being a date timestamp of when you created the element.

Try and see if this fits your requisites.

Change **$post_date** to a timestamp of the creation of your post. (E.G In this example below based on when I posted this answer shows 1 day...)

Wrap the code below in a function and pass in $post_date with the wordpress getDate feature with the timestamp ('7/25/2017 00:00:00') and the function will return hours, minutes, days.

```
$seconds_hours = 60*60;
$hours_days = $seconds_hours*24;

$today = date("Y-m-d");
$timestamp = $today.' '.date("H:i:s");

$post_date = '7/25/2017 00:00:00';

$difference = strtotime($timestamp)-strtotime($post_date);
if ($difference>$hours_days) {
    $date1 = new DateTime(substr($post_date,0,10));
    $date2 = new DateTime($today);
    $since = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%d");
    if ($since==1) { $since .= ' day'; }
    else { $since .= ' days'; }
} else if ($difference>$seconds_hours) {
    $since = floor($difference/$seconds_hours).' hours';
} else {
    $since = floor($difference/60).' mins';//mins
}

echo $since;
```

Wordpress Solution (Untested)

```
function human_difference($post_date) {
    $seconds_hours = 60*60;
    $hours_days = $seconds_hours*24;

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $timestamp = $today.' '.date("H:i:s");

    $difference = strtotime($timestamp)-strtotime($post_date);
    if ($difference>$hours_days) {
        $date1 = new DateTime(substr($post_date,0,10));
        $date2 = new DateTime($today);
        $since = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%d");
        if ($since==1) { $since .= ' day'; }
        else { $since .= ' days'; }
    } else if ($difference>$seconds_hours) {
        $since = floor($difference/$seconds_hours).' hours';
    } else {
        $since = floor($difference/60).' mins';//mins
    }

    return $since;
}

$post_date_time = get_the_date() . ' ' . get_the_time(); //Format this to m/d/Y H:i:s
echo human_difference($post_date_time); // x days or x hours or x minutes
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I got this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$post_date_time' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) on this line -  $post_date_time = get_the_date() . ' ' . get_the_time(); //Format this to m/d/Y H:i:s

Comment: Make sure to add in the correct format into  get_the_date and time. EG get_the_date('m/d/Y') etc

Answer (score 0):

put the below function in your `functions.php` file and just call `the_time();` and you get ago format date

```
function post_time_ago_format()
{
    return sprintf(esc_html__('%s ago', 'textdomain'), human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')));
}

add_filter('the_time', 'post_time_ago_format');
```